# Does glob work with pdf files?

Tags: python, pdf, concatenation, glob

I am new to python and I am trying to create a code that will search through thousands of pdf files that are organized and titled by 3 different numbers, township, range, and section (file looks like: 07N06E08_4200).  I have been trying to get glob to read my pdf files, as I have used glob for excel files, but I haven't had any luck.

This is the command so far to bring in the data:
         `glob.glob('./C:/Users/green_000/Documents/Alyssa/Python/FinalProject/Python_Data/SacramentoCounty')`

And that reutrns: []

I then have:

```
collectData=[] 

for filename in glob.glob('./C:/Users/green_000/Documents/Alyssa/Python/FinalProject/Python_Data/SacramentoCounty'): 
print('processing {:s}'.format(filename))
data = pd.read_pdf(filename) 
collectData.append(data) 
AllData = pd.concat(collectData)
AllData.columns=['Township','Range','Section'] 
AllData.to_pdf('AllData.csv',mode='w')
```

And I get the error: No objects to concatenate

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your path indicates that you are searching a relative path (starts with `.`) and also an absolute path (starts with `C:`). You can't do both simultaneously.

Try:

```
for filename in glob.glob('C:/Users/green_000/Documents/Alyssa/Python/FinalProject/Python_Data/SacramentoCounty'):
```

Comment: Of course, if you could be running in a UNIX-like environment, where `./C:/foo` is a legal path, but I doubt that you are.